# generate unique id across multiple tables jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There is a Base Entity class with id declared this way:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseEntity {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;...}
```

User Entity is inherited from this class.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class User extends BaseEntity {...}
```

Specific user entities like AdminUser are inherited from User class;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AdminUsers")
public class AdminUser extends User {...}
```

Is there a way to keep unique ID among different types of users, who are inherited from abstract User class?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by unique ID among different types? 
With JPA inheritance the ID is always unique in the whole inheritance Hierarchie.

Just a hint: TABLE_PER_CLASS is the worst inheritence strategy because it uses UNION when you query on the abstract User Level.

Comment: You should use generator type sequence if your db support sequence. If not you will have to generate the unique value across table.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I've checked the DB, I realized, that IDs of different types of users are just generated as a regular 1-2-3 sequence. 
I mean, in AdminUsers table I have IDs like 1,2,3...
And in CustomerUsers table (which is inherited in the same way as AdminUsers) I see the same IDs - 1,2,3...
Thus when I try to get user by id, I get multiple rows. But I have to get only one user, as far as I understand...